# What is the difference between threads and lightweight threads?

Tags: multithreading

I don't quite understand the difference between threads and lightweight threads. From an API perspective both types of threads are identical so where exactly does the difference come in. Is it at the implementation level where a lightweight thread is managed by a higher level runtime than the OS thread scheduler or is it something else? Also, is there set of heuristics that people use to decide which type of thread to use in specific scenarios?

Comment: Any context like OS/Platform/language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what context, lightweight threads could represent threads which are implemented by a library, for example threads can be simulated in a library by switching between lightweight threads at an event handling layer, these lightweight threads are queued up and processed by a singe OS thread, the advantage of this is that since context switching is handled in the library switching can occur when the processing of data is complete and so the data does not need to be loaded back into the CPU's cache next time this lightweight thread becomes active.

Lightweight threads could also refer to co-operative threads (or fibers), these are threads where you have to explicitly yield to give other lightweight threads a chance, this has the same advantage in that the context switching can occur at a place you know you have finished processing some data and so you know it will not be need again.

Alternativly Lightweight threads could mean normal OS threads and the non-lightweight threads could mean processes, process have at least one thread within them and also have there own memory and other resources, they are more expensive than threads because you can not share data between thread easily and it can be a more expensive operation for the OS to create processes.

Comment: At one time I remember threads were often called "lightweight processes".